# Variations of adjective forms

Tags: word-choice

1. A stripe shirt.
2. A stripes shirt.
3. A stripy shirt.
4. A striped shirt.

Which one sounds natural? What are the differences between them and when would you say #4 instead of 1,2, or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my (American) ear:

- "A stripe shirt" sounds like a mispronunciation of "A striped shirt".
- "A stripes shirt" does not sound natural.
- "A stripy shirt" sounds like something a young child might say.  In other words, it is natural, but not standard.  If an adult said "A stripy shirt", I would think they were deliberately trying to sound like a child.  The spelling "stripey" seems about as natural to me as "stripy".
- "A striped shirt" sounds natural, and is what I would normally say.

"A striped shirt" sounds more natural to me than "A shirt with stripes", but:

- "A shirt with two stripes" sounds more natural than "A two-striped shirt".
- "A blue shirt with white stripes" sounds more natural than "A white-striped blue shirt".
- "A shirt with blue and white stripes" might mean something different from "A blue-and-white striped shirt".
- The "star-spangled banner" has red and white stripes.

Comment: "The star-spangled banner" is a poetic phrase; it refers to the U.S. flag.  This phrase is the title of the American national anthem.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the normal thing is a striped shirt or a shirt with stripes. Your other variants are not common.
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/striped?q=striped

Comment: Thank you. then can you explain what image is invoked to your mine when two nouns come together like #1? When would you say the first form instead of the adjecttive noun form like #4?

Comment: I would not say it because the noun stripe is singular and I guess the shirt you have in mind has more than one stripe. Neither would I say stripes shirt because "striped shirt" is  a very common pattern of word formation. Wood forms wooded hills,  cap can form snow-capped mountains. Noun + ed means provided with. Wooded hills are hills provided with woods. A striped shirt is a shirt provided with stripes. As this pattern is very frequent, you can find hundreds of such formations, I would not use other possibilities.

Comment: Thank you again. Have you been to Gap.com? It's a clothing shop and you may see them label all their striped clothes with stripe skirt, tee, and so on.

Comment: Commercial language tries to invent expressions a bit different from normal language,  it draws the attention. But people would say: I bought two striped shirts.

Comment: *Stripey shirt* is okay colloquially.